# How to make sure that SpringBoot app is always up and running on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, spring-boot, jar, downtime

I have a Spring Boot app (jar file) that is running on Windows server and is used to sync data between some tables in a database and other parts of infrastructure (consumer apps via ActiveMQ).

It is crucial to have it running 24/7 without any downtime (or with very little).

I am currently trying to find the best way to do this as our current solution is to run multiple instances of the same app and define one to be active and ping it continuously (via an entry in database where it writes every 15 seconds), while other instances are just running and do nothing (inactive state, cause lock is taken). If an active instance has stopped to update lock entry (freeze or crashed) in database one of the available instances will take its place and start to handle data.

I have a feeling, that it is not so flexible solution, especially when I need to prepare different part of my code to check lock entry and sync all those instances. It adds complexity to the code and I want to avoid it.

Is there any better solution? Plugins, implementation pattern or tools?

PS: 
I read about health endpoints that are available in a SpringBootApplication and think that it can help me somehow (ping\check them from some other Watchdog software\tool, maybe?), but don't know how.

Comment: Kubernetes is used for cases like this. Now sure if you will be able to get it running on Windows server.

Comment: @tsolakp, yeah, the main problem is that host which is running jar is a Windows based, it could be more simple to install it as a service on Linux machine or run it trough Docker image.

Answer (score 2):

In case of a crash you still have a delay of 15 seconds while a request can fail

I would go with a zuul router from netflix (open source)

It will balance the load between instances and will retry your request on another instance if the first call has failed

I'm pretty sure it's already done but use windows services to restart instance in case of hard crash

Comment: yes, but 15 seconds we can live without updates (it will still pickup pending data whenever the app is restarted after crash). Mainly I want to avoid sitting with a crashed instance without knowing about it.

I will check this zuul router things, thanks for advice.